# Kinect depth pixel

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, kinect

I am working on a kinect project using MS Kinect SDK1.7.
When I am trying the sample code about bridging with OPENCV.
I am not understanding about the code of calculation
    // Convert depth info into an intensity for display
            BYTE b = 255 - static_cast(256 * realDepth / 0x0fff);

And how can I get the pixels from Mat back to the depth distance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with Kinect, but from that line I'm assuming that realDepth will be depth measured by their device inside Kinect, which is in some SI unit (since 0x0fff is 4096 I'm assuming mm). The line there

```
// Convert depth info into an intensity for display 
BYTE b = 255 - static_cast(256 * realDepth / 0x0fff);
```

then converts the depth value in mm into the range (0 - 255) so it can be displayed on the monitor screen.

You don't need to get depth 'back', you can just use `realDepth` directly